# ¿Mysql - Como sumar dos campos con un mismo nombre, agruparlos y contarlos?

Tags: mysql, sql

Buenos dias, espero me puedan ayudar con esta consulta, tengo este query:

```
SELECT at_ce.condicion, COUNT(*) AS cantidad
FROM at_cons_externa at_ce
GROUP BY at_ce.condicion
```

Y como resultado me da esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es armar UN SOLO query que sume del campo condicion los "CONFIRMADO" + "OBSERVADO" y otro que me sume "NO PASO CONSULTA" + "CONFIRMADO" + "OBSERVADO". Espero alguien me pueda ayudar, u orientar. Tal vez dentro se pueda manejar un "if" o relacionado.

Gracias...

Comment: ¿`condicion` es clave primaria? -- Usa `UNION` y la cláusula `WHERE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sin tener en cuenta optimizaciones y ciendo que son tablas pequeñas...:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cantidad INTO #TablaTemporalConfirmadoObservado
FROM at_cons_externa at_ce
where at_ce.condicion IN ('CONFIRMADO','OBSERVADO')

SELECT COUNT(*) AS cantidad INTO #TablaTemporalConfirmadoObservadoNoPaso
FROM at_cons_externa at_ce
where at_ce.condicion IN ('CONFIRMADO','OBSERVADO','NO PASO CONSULTA')

select t1.cantidad AS [Total Confirmado y Observado], t2.cantidad AS [Total Confirmado, Observado y No paso consulta]
from #TablaTemporalConfirmadoObservado t1,  #TablaTemporalConfirmadoObservadoNoPaso t2

drop table #TablaTemporalConfirmadoObservado
drop table #TablaTemporalConfirmadoObservadoNoPaso
```

Las tablas que empiezan por `#` son tablas que se crean al momento (temporales) pero es importante hacer un `drop table` al final para poder reutilizarlas.

A mi me gusta utilizar tablas temporales, pero si se quiere hacer en una única query...:

Con **UNION**:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Total Confirmado y Observado]
FROM at_cons_externa at_ce
where at_ce.condicion IN ('CONFIRMADO','OBSERVADO')
union
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Total Confirmado, Observado y No paso consulta] 
FROM at_cons_externa at_ce
where at_ce.condicion IN ('CONFIRMADO','OBSERVADO','NO PASO CONSULTA')
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono con UNION, lo de tablas temporales, me salio un error, de todas maneras, agradezco el tiempo :)!

Comment: Ningún problema. Aún así y por curiosidad, qué error te sale con las tablas temporales? Para corregir la respuesta.

Comment: Error de SQL (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM at_cons_externa at_cewhere at_ce.condicion IN ('CONFIRMADO','OBSERVADO')' at line 2

Answer (score 0):

hola te voy a recomendar algo mejor baja un programa llamado SQLyog Enterprise conectas tu mysql al programa y genera un query builder, solo debes arrastar y soltar vas seleccionando la tabla y los valores que desees y el solo genera el query lo copias y pegas en tu pagina y listo. ve un ejemplo en la foto[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]